# Quartz.net cron trigger fires only once

Tags: error-handling, quartz.net, repeat, crontrigger

Started using Quartz.net in my project. But got stuck.
 Using cron trigger fires only once, and stops. What may cause this problem?

Here are masks for cron trigger:

```
0 0/7 * * * ?
0 0/10 * * * ?
```

And they look good for me, also no exception raised in log. Do I have explicitly set some option to make cron trigger fire repeatedly?

Comment: Have you got any code you use to create jobs and triggers?

Comment: @LeftyX, thanks for attention. I've solved problem. Answer will be posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may got the same behaviour. Pay attention to you Job, try to manually run it few times, to check whether the next run won't cause exception.
 For me next run caused some windsor exception, and this exception didn't raised to second chance exception. I've founded it accidentally in debug window as first chance exception and later it was somehow handled by Quartz.dll.
 Pay attention to debug window in VS =] Sometimes it can make your day.